# RegEx capturing BBCode Quote username and ID

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

I'm looking to create some regex that will capture the username and post ID from BBCode QUOTE tags.

I only want the text to match when the username is directly followed by a post ID and is a fully formed QUOTE tag (e.g. [QUOTE=username;numericalid]

I'm currently using this:

```
$matches = preg_match_all('/(\[QUOTE=)(\w*?)(\;)/', $data, $match);
```

But this is matching with "QUOTE=Jim][QUOTE=Bob" from the text below, not just "[QUOTE=Bob".

I'm also trying to only return the username and ID, so the ideal return would be "Bob;20499344" (for every username/ID pattern in the text).

```
[QUOTE=Bob;204992][QUOTE=Steve;204939][QUOTE=Steve;204938][QUOTE=Steve;204936]Here is some text.

[QUOTE=Jim][QUOTE=Bob;20499344][QUOTE=Bob;203489194][QUOTE=Bob;67235994]some more quote here[/QUOTE][/QUOTE][/QUOTE][/QUOTE][/QUOTE][QUOTE=Bob;204194]

=hello;78967876]
```

How can I modify the regex to match this correctly?

Any help would be awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex and then work with group #1 to get your "ideal return":

```
\[QUOTE=([\w ]+;\d+)
```

`[\w ]+` looks for a user name (consisting of word characters and spaces; you might need to alter that to your actual restrictions), `\d+` looks for at least one digit.

[Small sample code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/85a7c2cf1108c8d91fe756501b16c705e50e4dcd):

```
<?php
$string = "[QUOTE=jim][QUOTE=bob;20499344][QUOTE=bob;203449194][QUOTE=bob;67204994]some more quote here[/QUOTE][/QUOTE][/QUOTE][/QUOTE][/QUOTE][QUOTE=bob;204994]";
$matches = preg_match_all('/\[QUOTE=([\w ]+;\d+)/', $string, $match);
print_r($match[1]);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => bob;20499344
    [1] => bob;203449194
    [2] => bob;67204994
    [3] => bob;204994
)
```